# echo is being performed by default php login page

Tags: php, authentication, echo

I am having trouble with getting the page to not echo when the user enters no username or password, this is because of my countreturnedrows() == 0 line. Any solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
        ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        ini_set("display_errors",1);

        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/flourish/toinclude.php";
        $mydb=new fDatabase("mssql", "finance","mytest","","ISOMTEACHING5\INFOSYS280",61495);
        $result = $mydb->query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE personname=%s AND password=%s", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if($result->countReturnedRows() == 0)
        {
            echo "Sorry, but your username and password that you have entered doesn't exist.";
        }
        else
        {
            $fetchresult = $result->fetchRow();
            $userid = $fetchresult['username'];
            $isadmin = $fetchresult['admin'];
            header("location:mainpage.php");
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: @Gumbo: What makes you think his code is vulnerable to SQL injections? Given the placeholders in the string and separately passing in the values, my assumption is that the `query()` method of `fDatabase` will sanitize this user input. And how would this fix the problem?

Comment: @Travesty3 You’re probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole thing in another if-statement:

```
if ($_POST['username'] != '' || $_POST['password'] != '')
{
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/flourish/toinclude.php";
    $mydb=new fDatabase("mssql", "finance","mytest","","ISOMTEACHING5\INFOSYS280",61495);
    $result = $mydb->query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE personname=%s AND password=%s", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    if($result->countReturnedRows() == 0)
    {
        echo "Sorry, but your username and password that you have entered doesn't exist.";
    }
    else
    {
        $fetchresult = $result->fetchRow();
        $userid = $fetchresult['username'];
        $isadmin = $fetchresult['admin'];
        header("location:mainpage.php");
    }
}
```

This way, it will skip the whole block if the user didn't enter either a username or a password.